# Python equivalent of C# Enum.HasFlag

Tags: python, enums

Lets say in python

```
StateA = 1
StateB = 2
StateC = StateA | StateB

...
instance.state = StateA
```

in C# there is a HasFlag function in Enum, which tells me an object's flag is part of StateC

Is there a equivalent version in python?

Right now I can only think (as bitwise noob) of this and not even sure if it supposed to work:

```
if instance.state | StateC == StateC:
    # yes in StateC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Testing for a flag:

```
value & flag == flag
```

Adding a flag:

```
value |= flag
```

Clearing a flag:

```
value &= ~flag
```

Answer (score 3):

**Python 3.4** has an [`Enum` data type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#module-enum), which [has been backported](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34).

```
from enum import Enum

class States(Enum):
    StateA = 1
    StateB = 2
    StateC = StateA | StateB
    def has_flag(self, flag):
        return self.value & flag.value

if States.StateC.has_flag(States.StateA):
    print("yup, it's there!")
```

---

**Python 3.6** has the [`(Int)Flag` data type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#intflag), which is also present in [the `aenum`<sup>1</sup> library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum):

```
from enum import Flag  # or from aenum import Flag

class States(Flag):
    StateA = 1
    StateB = 2
    StateC = StateA | StateB

if States.StateA in States.StateC:
    print("yup, it's there!")
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Answer (score 1):

[HasFlag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag(v=vs.110).aspx) is basically bitwise operation.

```
>>> a = 0b01
>>> b = 0b10
>>> "{0:b}".format(a | b,)
'11'
>>> def has_flag(v, flag): return v & flag == flag
...
>>> has_flag(0b111, a)
True
>>> has_flag(0b111, a|b)
True
>>> has_flag(0b1, a|b)
False
```