# Python metaclass to generate correct enum values for class

Tags: python, enums, metaclass

My [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25518988/python-equivalent-of-c-sharp-enum-hasflag) asked about Enum in python

Lets say I am creating State classes:

```
class State(object):
    """
    Abstract class representing a state.
    """
    enum = 1

    def __init__(self, instance):
        self.instance = instance

    def is_flag(self, flag):
        return flag & self.enum == self.enum
```

And then I create different actual States

```
class New(State):
    enum = 2
    def pay(self):
        ...

class Paid(State):
    enum = 4
    def complete(self):
        ...

class Completed(State):
    enum = 8


ACCOUNTABLE = Paid.enum | Completed.enum
```

while this works, I would like to automate the generation of the enum values, and it seems like it can be done by using Meta classes, the question is how?

Comment: Abstract base classes aren't the same thing a metaclasses. Regardless, creating separate classes with an attribute holding a single integer value seems like an awfully heavy-weight approach to creating Enum values. Another issue with this approach is that the integer values generated could vary depending on the order and number of of subclasses defined -- which means they wouldn't be constant values, something which is often desirable for enumerations.

Comment: I have also considered the inconsistent values can be generated by the metaclass. I want to implement StateMachine pattern not just the Enum.

Comment: It's unclear how the StateMachine pattern would make it possible to avoid the issue of inconsistent values. Also your use of `ABCMeta` is unnecessary, both here and in the answer you posted to your own question. In Python abstract base classes aren't the same thing as they are in, say, C++. If you insist on using classes to represent different Enum values -- a questionable approach -- a metaclass is probably all you'd need.

Comment: OK thanks, I have removed the ABCMeta, I thought of using that `ABCMeta` could stop accidentally instating `State` class. I have also noticed the possible inconsistent enum values being generated, so in my actual implementation I have commented out the metaclass and specify the enum explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't think defining a separate class for each enum value is a very robust approach for the reasons stated in my comments, here's one way it could be done which will support the creation of multiple independent base state classes.

```
class MetaState(type):
    _baseclasses = {}  # registry of instances & number of subclasses of each
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        cls = super(MetaState, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
        if bases == (object,):  # definition of a base class?
            MetaState._baseclasses[cls] = 0  # create initial registry entry
        else:  # must be derived from a previously defined base state class
            for base in bases:  # find base state class
                if base in MetaState._baseclasses:
                    setattr(cls, 'enum', 2 ** MetaState._baseclasses[base])
                    MetaState._baseclasses[base] += 1
                    break
            else:
                raise TypeError('Class not derived from base state class')
        return cls

class BaseState(object):
    """ Abstract base class for each derived state subclass. """
    __metaclass__ = MetaState

    def is_flag(self, flag):
        return flag & self.enum == self.enum

class A(BaseState): pass
class B(BaseState): pass
class C(BaseState): pass

print A.enum  # -> 1
print B.enum  # -> 2
print C.enum  # -> 4
```

Answer (score 3):

Python 3.4 has an [`Enum` data type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#module-enum), which [has been backported](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34).

```
from enum import IntEnum

States = IntEnum('States', [(n, 2**i) for i, n in enumerate('New Paid Complete'.split(), 1)])

list(States) # [<States.New: 2>, <States.Paid: 4>, <States.Complete: 8>]
```

or

```
class States(IntEnum):
    New = 2
    Paid = 4
    Complete = 8
    def is_flag(self, flag):
        return self & flag == flag
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also come up a solution (needs fixing) for my answer:

```
class StateMeta(type):

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        cls = super(StateMeta, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
        if bases[-1] == object:
            return cls

        setattr(cls, 'enum', 2 ** (len(bases[-1].__subclasses__())-1))
        return cls


class State(object):
    """
    Abstract class representing a state.
    """
    __metaclass__ = StateMeta

    enum = 0

    def __init__(self, instance):
        self.instance = instance

    def is_flag(self, flag):
        return flag & self.enum == self.enum
```

Running it:

```
>>> class A(State):
...     pass
... 
>>> A.enum
1
>>> class B(State):
...     pass
... 
>>> B.enum
2
```

Comment: Why are you skipping an enum value of 1 (2**0)?

Comment: I am not skipping in purpose, but I cannot use the power of the iterator value because it's generating the enum value in a single class scope.

Comment: `StateMeta.__new__()` is called when class `State` is defined, as well as when classes `A` and `B` are (because the latter two inherit `State`'s metaclass), so I don't understand what you mean by a "single class scope".

Comment: I guess you are right, when creating A class, the count of subclass of State should be 1 (before B gets created), so I can possibly use use 2**(len(_cls.__subclasses__())-1) to create enum value.